# ServiceStack - Persist session on different cache provider

Tags: session, caching, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I use MemoryCache in several places in my web app to improve performance.
The problem is that from time to time I get logged-out although the session should not have expired. If I change the cache provider to OrmLite it does not happen but the overall performance is lower.
Is there a way of using OrmLite cache provider to persist session state while continuing to use MemoryCache overall the application.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using MemoryCacheClient your sessions get lost whenever the AppDomain recycling.

To avoid this you can use any of the other [distributed caching providers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching). The Redis CacheClient offers better performance than an RDBMS OrmLite cache.

ServiceStack only supports registering a single `ICacheClient` dependency for its built-in components, but you can still register and use a `MemoryCacheClient` in your own Services, e.g:

```
container.Register(new MemoryCacheClient());
```

Which you can access like a normal dependency:

```
public class MyServices : Service
{
    public MemoryCacheClient MemoryCache { get; set; }

    public object Any(Request request)
    {
         return base.Request.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(
            MemoryCache, "urn:customers", () => {
                return Db.Select<Customer>();
            });

    }
}
```